# How to design code and db to handle multiple webervice versions

Tags: java, web-services, versioning

I am currently working on an application which is designed to host web-services to be consumed by multiple external applications. The application will roll out enhancements as well as changes to the existing web-services as well as to add new services. I am looking for best practices to manage and support multiple web-service versions. Most importantly trying to solve following 2 problem statements:

1. How to design web-services and support backward compatibility, specifically in scenarios where the same service is getting enhanced between 2 versions.
2. How to design the DB which needs to support existing webservice functionality and any enhancement for future versions.

The application is based on Java (using Apache CXF & Oracle).

I understand there may not be any direct answers but any input or link in the right direction would help.

Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is broad and designs are specific. That's why it is called a Requirement Specification. It is hard to tell good design practices for broad requirements.

Comment: Thanks Shazin. I understand the issue is broad but I was expecting it to be a common design problem. Unfortanely I havent come across many topics or discussion covering this.